# Downloading a text from a URL that is password protected by a different URL (Java)

Tags: java, apache, http, authentication, password-protection

I have a URL with data I would like to access. The data is in text form and it is password protected...but here's the thing...it is password protected by a *different* website. I have spent *weeks* on this issue. When I use Apache HttpClient, I can log into the login URL just fine, but I cannot figure out how to gain access to the data URL. Every time I try to gain access to the data URL, I get an HTTP 500 error. Any suggestions for this issue? I don't think this is a very common problem considering I have not come across it in my many Stackoverflow and Google searches. THANK YOU SO MUCH IF YOU CAN HELP :)

Below is an example of one of the programs I have tried using to no avail...(Some of the information is private, so I changed the username, password, and url)

```
package Apache1;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

/**
 * A simple example that uses HttpClient to execute an HTTP request against
 * a target site that requires user authentication.
 */
public class Apache2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 443),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myUsername", "myPW"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("LOGIN URL");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());

                        URL oracle = new URL("DATA URL");
                        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                    yc.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                            System.out.println(inputLine);
                        in.close(); 



            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my most recent code to handle the cookies. I keep getting a HTTP 500 error.

```
package Apache1;
//import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

/**
 * A simple example that uses HttpClient to execute an HTTP request against
 * a target site that requires user authentication.
 */
public class Apache2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 443),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myUSERNAME", "myPASSWORD"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("LOGIN_WEBSITE");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());

                        URL oracle = new URL("DATA_WEBSITE");
                        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                    yc.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                            System.out.println(inputLine);
                        in.close(); 



            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried using the Authenticator to no avail

Comment: What do you mean, it's password protected by a different website? You still have to send data to that url and get data back. I think you need to explain in more details how things work.

Comment: The data URL uses cookies to work. For instance, I can only access it when I am logged into the login URL. If I log out of the login URL and reload the data URL, I get an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Then read the cookie from the first response headers, and use it for the second request.

Comment: I tried that but was unsuccessful. Do you have an example of code that I could reference?

Comment: post the code you used for the cookie. Dump all the responses header you get from the URL.

Comment: I have posted my code above. I am relatively new to Java, so I do not fully understand each line, just what it's trying to do.